# GUARD_PAGE memory breakpoints with gdb?

Tags: ida, gdb, memory, breakpoint

I came across a question the other day on reddit: How can we use PAGE_GUARD-based memory breakpoints in GDB (not hardware breakpoints)?

Ollydbg, x64dbg and IDA PRO all support these types of breakpoints, but I couldnt find a way in GDB.

If this is not available, is it possible to set the PAGE_GUARD bit manually in GDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man mmap`

> ```
>   PROT_NONE  The memory cannot be accessed at all.
>   PROT_READ  The memory can be read.
>   PROT_WRITE The memory can be modified.
>   PROT_EXEC  The memory can be executed.
> ```

`PROT_NONE` will act like a guard page by hitting a `SIGSEGV` when accessed.

The page with `PROT_NONE` looks like this in the map during runtime

```
    0x7ffff7ff7000     0x7ffff7ff8000 ---p     1000 0
```

`gdb` allows you to call arbitrary functions in the process space. A simple solution would be to run this under gdb

```
print mprotect($address,0x1000,0)
```

This would set `PROT_NONE` = 0 permissions on the page and it will act as a guard page.
If after hitting `SIGSEGV` you want to remap the page as rw (PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE)

```
print mprotect($address,0x1000,3)
```

If you want to add an extra page mapped as guard page like the page heaps in windows, you can call mmap.

```
print /a mmap($address+0x1000,0x1000,0,0x22,-1,0)
```

Here 0x22 is `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised though gdb doesnt offer it directly.

Comment: Hm, another thing: is there really no way to get the current protection of the page? Otherwise it  would be hard to undo the memory-breakpoint and expose me to anti-debugging actions.

Comment: There's no way to read the protections from any api/syscall. Worst case you can parse `/proc/<pid>/maps`. Some gdb extensions like `pwndbg` give a `vmmap` command which does this.